# Как открыть файловый диалог в Python?

Tags: python

Мне нужно вызвать меню выбора папки, выбрать папку и получить ее путь.
Как это сделать без PyQt5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лично я использую в таких ситуациях easygui. Это упрощённая версия tkinter (да, можно было бы использовать сам tkinter, но в easygui это окно можно вызвать в одну команду без предварительных команд)

```
import easygui    
dirpath = easygui.diropenbox()
```

Comment: А можно ли использовать стандартные способы или библиотеку os?

Comment: @NIGVUL os вообще не этим занимается, он просто работает с системой, стандартными способами тоже вряд ли, так как это gui.